# Using project_loc and workspace_loc in environment variables in an Eclipse launcher?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is anyone using the variables ${project_loc} and ${workspace_loc} in environment variables in an Eclipse launcher? I'm trying to use them, primarily ${project_loc} but nearly every time I run my launcher I get the following:

> Variable references empty selection: ${project_loc}

I have four environment variables defined, two of which use ${project_loc}, though I've also tried ${workspace_loc}. These Maven projects were created outside of Eclipse and then imported as "Existing Maven projects". This may have something to do with the problem but I'm confused as to how to proceed.

Is anyone using these environment variables successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description in the help for 'project_loc' says

> Returns the absolute file system path of a resource's project. The
>   target resource is the selected resource when no argument is
>   specified, or the resource identified by a workspace relative path.

So `${project_loc}` returns the project containing the current selection - if there is no selection you get the error. It is better to use an argument to project_loc:

```
${project_loc:/MyProject}
```

Comment: I should point out that I tried the equivalent of ${project_loc:MyProject}, but I forgot the slash. So thanks, you gave me the answer, it appears to work.

Comment: Eclipse is getting confused with this working launcher. I created a new launcher with two environment variables, using ${project_loc}, that does start the application, but Eclipse is showing four copies of the same launcher in the menu. If I delete one entry, they are all deleted.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question

Comment: I wonder why it ever pays attention to the tree selection if there's explicit project selector in the launch configuration main tab.

Comment: @tequilacat These variables can be used in several places in Eclipse, using the selection makes more sense in some of the other places (External Tools Configuration for example).